# Set Bootstrap Modal text dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to set the modal text after it's been launched by a jQuery click event, but I'm unsuccesful. Can somebody give me some pointers?

I have tried setting the title, body and button dynamically, but for some reason it's not added.

```
$(function() {
    $(".contact-input-plus").on( "click",  "a", function() {
        if ( ! $(this).is(".remove")) {
           // Do stuff
        } else {
            $('#confirm').modal('show');
            $('#confirm').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
                var modal = $(this);
                modal.find('.modal-body p').text('You are about to remove this entry. Are you sure?');
                modal.find('.modal-header h4').html('Remove entry');
                modal.find('.modal-footer a.btn').text('Remove');
            });

        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Note:** I need to clarify something. The modal is displayed firstly without the text set. When I cancel and fire the modal again, the text is inserted.

Comment: Is `$('#confirm').modal('show');` firing properly? Is `! $(this).is(".remove")` evaluating the way you intend it to?

Comment: Yes, it's firing properly. But the text values are not added to the modal the first time - only from the second time on ...

Comment: So opening the modal on the first attempt the text is not added, but on subsequent attempts it is?

Comment: Exactly like you describe it, indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the dynamic stuff before calling the .show() like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".contact-input-plus").on( "click",  "a", function() {
        if ( ! $(this).is(".remove")) {
           // Do stuff
        } else {
                var modal = $('#confirm');
                modal.find('.modal-body p').text('You are about to remove this entry. Are you sure?');
                modal.find('.modal-header h4').html('Remove entry');
                modal.find('.modal-footer a.btn').text('Remove');

            $('#confirm').modal('show');

        }
        return false;
    });
});
```